# нужна помощь с объединением массива и строки С++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

У меня есть массив `wchar_t * buffer` который хранит директорию запущенной программы.
Как объединить его с другим текстом?
Допустим я пытаюсь открыть файл, находящийся в этой директории:

```
ifstream file; 
file.open(buffer + "\\myDoc.txt";
```

но конкатенация не работает, как тогда можно реализовать?
Пробовал еще `file.open(buffer, "\\myDoc.txt";` и еще
 `std::string directory = buffer + "\\myDoc";  file.open(directory);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
std::ifstream file;
file.open(buffer + std::wstring(L"\\myDoc.txt"));
```

Или вот так

```
std::ifstream file;
file.open(std::wstring(buffer) + L"\\myDoc.txt");
```

Comment: За пределами Visual Studio может [не компилироваться](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ecb4d2b8f484ac3c).